# How to change scale during making a new geom using ggplot2 in R ?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, geom-bar

I'd like to make a new geom geom_spine() : This geom is similar with geom_bar() but the barwidth varies depending on the count.

Here is what I tried.

```
require(ggplot2)

"%||%" <- function(a, b) {
     if (!is.null(a)) a else b
}

geom_spine <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                       stat = "count", position = "fill",
                       color="black",size=0.2,
                       ...,
                       width = NULL,
                       binwidth = NULL,
                       na.rm = FALSE,
                       show.legend = NA,
                       inherit.aes = TRUE) {

     layer(
          data = data,
          mapping = mapping,
          stat = stat,
          geom = GeomSpine,
          position = position,
          show.legend = show.legend,
          inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
          params = list(
               width = width,
               na.rm = na.rm,
               color=color,
               size=size,
               ...
          )
     )

}

colcount=function(data){
     result=c() 
     myx=unique(data$x)
     for(i in 1:length(myx)) result=c(result,sum(data[data$x==myx[i],"count"]))
     result                                     
}

GeomSpine <- ggproto("GeomSpine", GeomRect,
                     required_aes = c("x", "y"),

                     setup_data = function(data, params) {

                          data$width <- data$width %||%
                               params$width %||% (resolution(data$x, FALSE) * 0.9)

                          sumc<-c(0,colcount(data))
                          sumc<-cumsum(sumc)
                          total<-sum(data$y)/(length(unique(data$x))+1)

                          data1<-transform(data,
                                           ymin = pmin(y, 0), ymax = pmax(y, 0),
                                           xmin=sumc[x]+(sumc[x+1]-sumc[x])*(1-width)/2,xmax=sumc[x+1]-sumc[x+1]*(1-width)/2)
                          data<-transform(data1,
                                           xmin=xmin/total,xmax=xmax/total,          
                                           x=(xmin+xmax)/(2*total), width=xmax-xmin
                          )
                          data

                     },

                     draw_panel = function(self, data, panel_scales, coord, width = NULL) {

                          ggproto_parent(GeomRect,self)$draw_panel(data, panel_scales, coord)
                     }
)
```

With this code, I am able to draw this plot. But I am not able to position the x labels in the middle of bar.

```
ggplot(data=mpg,aes(x=drv,fill=factor(cyl)))+geom_spine()
```

[image]

But what I want is this : The labels for x axis are in the middle of bars.

[image]

I am not able to fix this problem. The scale_x_continuous() function results in 
"Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

How can I change the x axis to the continuous scale during defining a new geom?

Comment: your mapping currently has a discrete variable (drv) for x. I wonder if you shouldn't define a new stat and map the results to x, like `..density..` or `..count..` etc. in the case of `stat_density`. In other words, I don't think this is something you can do in a geom.